# PL/SQL output formatting

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

PL/SQL output formatting

As seen in the output window

```
old:declare

   num1 int; 
begin

    num1:= &enter_num1;
    dbms_output.put_line(num1);  
end;

new:declare

   num1 int; 
begin

    num1:= 102;
    dbms_output.put_line(num1);  
end;
102


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

is shown, but I want only

```
102


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

to be shown. Any Suggestions.....

Answer (score 2):

In SQL*Plus, it is `set verify off` that fixes the issue:

This is what you have:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    num1 int;
  3  begin
  4    num1 := &enter_num1;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(num1);
  6  end;
  7  /
Enter value for enter_num1: 102
old   4:   num1 := &enter_num1;
new   4:   num1 := 102;
102

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

With `set verify off`:

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> /
Enter value for enter_num1: 102
102

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```